# Oracle SQL Functions For Where Clause

Tags: oracle12c

I'm wondering if it is possible to create functions in Oracle SQL that can be used concisely inside of a WHERE clause.

I'd like to achieve something similar to the code below:

```
SELECT 'Hey'
FROM DUAL
WHERE TrimEquals('  hey', ' hey  ')
```

I'm not sure if this is possible.
I've seen examples where the function TrimEquals returns a value (usually 0 or 1) and you then compare that value like in the following example:

```
SELECT 'Hey'
FROM DUAL
WHERE TrimEquals('  hey', ' hey  ') = 1
```

Maybe I'm just being too picky but I don't like putting in the relational operator every time.

So, is this something I can do or am I stuck using the style from the second example?

Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not possible. Oracle SQL does not support Boolean values - though PL\SQL does.

Comment: Simply use `WHERE TRIM('  hey2') = TRIM('  hey2')` ,  don't be picky :-)

Comment: That's too bad, but thanks for the answer Strikegently